# How to work with selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to convert perfectly working macro to hyperlink with activedoccument.range to selection.range.

code is

```
With Selection.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "String String1"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    strtxt = Split(.Text, " ")(1)
    strtxt = Right(strtxt, 2) & "/" & Left(strtxt, 4) & "/" & Mid(strtxt, 8, 2) & "/" & Mid(strtxt, 5, 3)
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Duplicate, Address:="Address" & strtxt & "/0.pdf", TextToDisplay:=.Text
    .End = .Fields(1).Result.End
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
```

How to collapse correctly to make this work. Currently it hyperlinks all in the doccument instead selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the problem is basically that the found range's end needs to be increased by 1 when the hyperlink is inserted. But I believe you also have to check that you have not gone past the original Selection.Range end, so you need an additional test.

This seemed OK in Tables, but (a) I am currently testing in Mac Word 2011, which may well be different, and (b), if you actually select a column or noncontiguous ranges, you would have to work a lot harder to make the changes only in the selection (because of well-known lack of support for such selections).

```
Sub fandr()
Const strText As String = "String String1"
Dim dr As Word.Range
Dim sr As Word.Range
Set sr = Selection.Range
'Debug.Print sr.Start, sr.End
Set dr = sr.Duplicate
' Try to deal with the problem where Find fails to find
' the Find text if it is exactly the same as the selection
sr.Collapse wdCollapseStart
With sr.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = strText
  .Replacement.Text = ""
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Format = False
  .MatchWildcards = True
  Do While .Execute(Replace:=False)
    If sr.InRange(dr) Then
      'Debug.Print sr.Start, sr.End, dr.Start, dr.End
      strtxt = Split(.Text, " ")(1)
      strtxt = Right(strtxt, 2) & "/" & Left(strtxt, 4) & "/" & Mid(strtxt, 8, 2) & "/" & Mid(strtxt, 5, 3)
      sr.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sr, Address:="Address" & strtxt & "/0.pdf", TextToDisplay:=.Text
      sr.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      sr.End = sr.End + 1
      sr.Start = sr.End
      'Debug.Print sr.Start, sr.End, dr.Start, dr.End
    Else
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop
End With
Set sr = Nothing
Set dr = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly with my office 2007 (at home). Will test at work on Monday with 2010 and tell. I Think It'll Work.

Answer (score 0):

So I have changed a few things. Somehow the `Range` was getting messed up after adding the HyperLink. so I just reset the `SearchRange` after adding the hyperlink.

This will work perfectly if the selection is not part of a `Table` I have added some checks to see if its in side the table but dont have time now to complete the cell shift.

```
  Sub SearchTextAddHyperLink()

      Dim SearchRange As Range
      Dim OriginalRange As Range
      Dim FoundRange As Range
      Set SearchRange = Selection.Range
      Set OriginalRange = Selection.Range

      Dim strtxt As String
      Dim SearchText As String
      Dim CellPosition As String
      SearchText = "String String1"

      With SearchRange
           With .Find
           .ClearFormatting
           .Replacement.ClearFormatting
           .Text = SearchText
           .Replacement.Text = ""
           .Forward = True
           .Wrap = wdFindStop
           .Format = False
           .MatchWildcards = True

           End With

           Do While .Find.Execute
           '.Select
                If .Find.Found = True Then

                     Set FoundRange = SearchRange
                     FoundRange.Select
                     strtxt = Split(.Text, " ")(1)
                     strtxt = Right(strtxt, 2) & "/" & Left(strtxt, 4) & "/" & Mid(strtxt, 8, 2) & "/" & Mid(strtxt, 5, 3)
                     .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Duplicate, Address:="Address" & strtxt & "/0.pdf", TextToDisplay:=.Text


                      If Not FoundRange.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
                          'Resetting the SearchRange for outside a table
                          'For some reason the Hyperlink messes up the Range
                          'Len(SearchText) + 1 just caters for the changing the Search Text
                          'and adding an additional character to move passed the hyperlink
                          SearchRange.Start = FoundRange.End + Len(SearchText) + 1
                          SearchRange.End = OriginalRange.End
                     Else
                          'Resetting the SearchRange for inside a table
                          'Need to then be clever with determinign which cell you are in and then moving to the next cell
                          'SearchRange.Start = FoundRange.End  'Len(SearchText) + 1
                          'SearchRange.End = OriginalRange.End

                     End If
                End If
                'Just to check the SearchRange
                SearchRange.Select
           Loop

      End With

 End Sub
```

**NOTE:** Also, remember to also `Dim` all your variables going forward.

Comment: At least in tables, it Doesn't work. It hyperlinks everything. Problem is with collapse method. I need to find correct one.

Comment: @Rahul, on my Office 2010, it works perfectly if the text is in a Table. What version are you using?

Comment: Can we chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101986/how-to-work-with-selection